# regarding A in a laptop battery charger

Tags: power-supply

My HP laptop battery charger's input is 1.7A. Can I replace it with one that is 3.5A. Every other spec is the same on the input and output. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think the site you may find more help at is [su]. This is off topic for our site.

Answer (score 3):

It is okay to use a power supply with a higher current rating. The laptop will only use the current it needs. You do need to be certain that the voltage potential, and if it is AC or DC need all to be the same. Also the connector needs to be the same including the correct polarity.